# How to specify site-specific volumes for docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mounted-volumes

I'm working on a project with multiple collaborators; to share code and compute environment, we've setup a github repository which includes a `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` file. I can work on code and my collaborators can just pull the repository, run `docker-compose up` and have access to my jupyter notebooks in the same environment that I develop them.

The only problem with this is that, because we are working at different sites, the data that we are computing over is in different locations. So on my end, I want my `docker-compose.yml` to include:

```
  volumes:
    - /mnt/shared/data:/data
```

while my collaborators need it to say something like

```
  volumes:
    - /Volumes/storage/data:/data
```

I get that one way to do this would be to use an environment variable; in the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
  volumes:
    - "$DATA_PATH":/data
```

This forces them to run something like:

```
DATA_PATH=/Volumes/storage/data docker-compose up
```

As a solution, this isn't necessarily a problem, but it feels clunky to me, and fails to be self-documenting in the repository. I can wrap docker-compose in a shell script (a potential solution to almost any problem), but this also feels clunky. I can't help but suspect that there's a better solution here. Does docker-compose allow for this kind of functionality? Is there a best-practices way of accomplishing this? If not, I'm curious if anyone knows what the motivation behind excluding this functionality might be and/or why it isn't considered a good idea.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are extremely close. What I would add is, that you have a host specific `.env` file, see [Environment variables in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file), on each computer, in the same folder as the `docker-compose.yml`, with

```
DATA_PATH=/mnt/shared/data
```

or whatever value for `DATA_PATH` you like. Just add that `.env` to your `.gitignore`, so that every host keeps his own config off the repository and that's it.

Comment: Ahh, thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! For others who find this, here's the relevant documentation link: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file

Comment: Thanks for the link, you are right, it's always better to provide documentation links, I will add this to the answer.