# How to configure external bind volumes specified in .env for docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Trying to figure out a flexible bind mount, that survives a `docker compose down`

### Setup

I have a `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    restart: always
    command: redis-server --requirepass ${REDIS_PASSWORD}
    environment:
      - REDIS_PASSWORD=${REDIS_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: redis_data
        target: /data
    ports:
      - ${REDISPORT}:6379

volumes:
  redis_data:
    external: true
    name: "redis_data"
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: "none"
      o: "bind"
      device: ${VOLUME_REDIS}
```

and an `.env` file:

```
#Docker Test
REDIS_PASSWORD=supersecret
REDISPORT=6379
VOLUME_REDIS=/Users/stephan/temp/redis
```

### The problem

When I start `docker-compose up` I get the error:

> conflicting parameters "external" and "driver" specified for volume "redis_data"

However the [documentation seems to suggest](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volume-configuration-reference), that parameter are supported in the current version:

> For version 3.3 and below of the format, external cannot be used in conjunction with other volume configuration keys (driver, driver_opts, labels). This limitation no longer exists for version 3.4 and above.

When I remove the `driver` entry, the error changes to:

> conflicting parameters "external" and "driver_opts" specified for volume "redis_data"

### Environment

- Docker version 20.10.6, build 370c289
- docker-compose version 1.29.1, build c34c88b2 (but I used `docker compose` on macOS)
- OS: macOS Catalina & Ubuntu 20.04 (tested on both)

### What I'm trying to achieve

- Have all variables in `.env` files, so I can start the same `docker-compose.yml` multiple times by specifying different env files
- Avoid that a `docker-compose down` wipes my volumes
- use host bind, so I can process data (with Docker stopped) with host apps

### Stuff I looked at

- [Conditionalizing bind mounted volumes for Docker Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66038560/conditionalizing-bind-mounted-volumes-for-docker-compose)
- [How to specify site-specific volumes for docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52857974/how-to-specify-site-specific-volumes-for-docker-compose)

What do I miss?

Comment: Can you use the older/shorter bind-mount syntax; `volumes: ['${VOLUME_REDIS}:/data']` without creating a named volume?

Comment: I verified: you use this format, the bind is not considered "external" and, despite being a bind mount, `docker compose down` will wipe the data. So my goal "volume survive a `docker compose down`" fails

Comment: When you say "wipe the data", what happens?  That volume syntax (assuming `$VOLUME_REDIS` contains a `/` somewhere) connects a host directory directly to a container directory; you should be able to see the content in the host directory, and `docker-compose down` shouldn't touch it.  (I've seen several recent bugs reported on SO around `docker compose` built into the standard `docker` tool.)

Comment: It does. Run the sample. Add a few entries to Redis. docker compose down. docker compose up -> Redis is empty